# Which files within a win 7 cd report info about exact license type

Tags: windows-7, license

As described in title I'm looking for a way to know which type of license come with a Win7 (Pro SP1) CD: Retail, OEM and so on...
But I'm interested in understanding which files contained in installation CD have info about license type.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its simple.  If it is an OEM machine and came with Windows then it then the license was an OEM license.  There is no other way to tell besides just simply looking for the COA..

Comment: So if you have got a win7 CD without its COA label (nor its box) you are not able to know if it can be used for installation on a particular licensed machine, did you mean that?

Comment: If you just have an installation disk then you don't have a license key so its pretty useless.  The disk can install any version you want by editing a text document

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open `sources\ei.cfg` from the disc in any text editor and it may give you a hint. It will contain text like the following:

```
[EditionID]
Ultimate
[Channel]
Retail
[VL]
0
```

**EditionID** is obviously the version that should be installed (*Starter / HomeBasic / HomePremium / Professional / Ultimate*). If you delete ei.cfg from the setup media (say by creating your own disc or if you're using a USB stick to install), Windows Setup will prompt you to select the version to be installed. You can also use OEM or retail keys with the same media, unlike the case earlier before Vista.

**Channel** can be either *OEM / Retail*.

**VL** stands for Volume License and can be either *1* (for True) or *0* (for False).